# Razor create link to route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, routes

I've just installed Elmah in my MVC application. It magically added a route in Web.config:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
```

Which I can access through:

```
localhost/elmah
```

How can I create a link to this action in Razor?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.RouteLink("elmah")
```

or

```
<a href="/elmah">elmah</a>
```